# 19612 Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, kivy, exe

have a problem,
I can start my application but when I click on a button to import a file, the application crashes and shows me this:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg6BM.jpg)
i use kivy lib, plyer is the probleme.
thank's

I would like to be able to import images without worries so that the user can personalize the application
thank's :)

Comment: no possible way this can be answered with so little information.  ideally, you would have runnable code pasted into the question.  To have code show as code it needs extra indentation - use 4 spaces extra so in some IDE you can highlight all the code and tab key to indent the code before copy/paste into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].